# How can i check file path using xp_fileexist

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code to update file path in sql server first i want to check if the file exist in the folder if it doesn't exist update otherwise skip. i used `EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path, @result` but i get

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10 The multi-part identifier
>   "[WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX].[itemId]" could not be bound.

```
declare @result as int 
declare @path as nvarchar(3000) 
set @path= '\\XY-SERVER\Data\PRODUCTION\VAULT\200000 - 399999 \PDF\'+[WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX].[itemId]+'.pdf' 
EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path, @result OUTPUT 

if @result=1 
 update [WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX] 
 set [docPath] = @path FROM [WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX]  where itemId LIKE'500%'
else  
 update [WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX] set [docPath] ='' FROM [WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX]  where itemId LIKE'500%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The update statement doesn't look right. Remove `FROM [WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX]` between the `Set` statement and the `Where` clause.

```
  if @result=1 
     update [WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX] 
     set [docPath] = @path  
     where itemId LIKE'500%'
    else      
      update [WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX] 
      set [docPath] ='' 
         where itemId LIKE'500%'
```

Comment: my problem is on this line `set @path= '\\XY-SERVER\Data\PRODUCTION\VAULT\200000 - 399999 \PDF\'+[WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX].[itemId]+'.pdf'` the pdf files are saved based on itemid in WITEMX table. How can i replace the concatenate i think the concatenate creating the problem

Comment: Ah... I feel dumb... You need to select that Item from the table first. Can you pass that filename in as a parameter? Or do a select above into a variable.

Comment: how do i select item from the table first? thats my problemand get the file path as  `set @path= '\\XY-SERVER\Data\PRODUCTION\VAULT\200000 - 399999 \PDF\itemId.pdf'` sql doesnt like `[WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX].[itemId]` part. what option do i ha e